# Entity Framework insert produces empty column in SQL Server LocalDB

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am performing an insert operation with Entity Framework 5.

My code inserts a new row from a user input and parsed values in another method. The debug operation shows all object attributes have a value before the insert operation is called, the code executes without any exception, and the row is updated in the `LocalDb`, but content column value is missing or never saved.

Here is my entity framework code:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostFormData()
{
        var profile = db.ProfileRepository.dbSet.Where(m => m.profileId == 1).FirstOrDefaultAsync().Result;

        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        var research = new Research();
        research.profile = profile;
        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/documentSafe");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        try
        {
            // Read the form data.
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            research.title = provider.FormData["title"];
            research.researchAbstract = provider.FormData["researchAbstract"];
            research.publisher = provider.FormData["publisher"];
            var areaList = new List<ResearchArea>();
            string areas = provider.FormData["researchArea"];

            foreach (var r in areas.Split(','))
            {
                var area = new ResearchArea()
                {
                    name = r,
                    departmentId = profile.departmentId
                };
                areaList.Add(area);
            }

            research.researchArea = areaList;

            research.researchType = new ResearchType()
            {
                name = provider.FormData["type"]
            };

            string content = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(parser.convert(provider.FileData[0]));
            research.content = content;

            using (var context = new AcademicContext())
            {
                context.Research.Add(research);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();                  
            }

            return Ok(); 
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return InternalServerError(e);
        }
    }
```

The missing column is a parsed html string encoded using webutility and has an average size of 15,000 characters. I have checked the database column attribute too, and it is set to `nvarchar(MAX)`.

If I insert a sample plain text to the column, the value get saved, but if I pass the encoded html string it does not.

Any suggestions why my column will not be null but still not contain any value.

Solution: The sql server explorer in visual studio seem to display an empty column when the character size is greater than 4000. I ran multiple test to verity this. I could get the content of the empty column by running raw sql select query.